# Only do an action if content has not changed in 500ms

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

currently I have

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('input').keyUp(function(){
    $('#output').text($(this).text());
  });
});
```

What I want to do is,

When a keypress is registered wait 500ms,
if a key is pressed again within that 500ms,
wait 500ms from that keypress.

once the 500ms has gone by,
run the `$('#output').text($(this).text());`

How would I go about managing the timeout?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set and clear a timer, like this:

```
$(function(){
  $('input').keyup(function(){
    clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
    var input = this;
    $.data(this, 'timer', setTimeout(function() {
      $('#output').text($(input).text());
    }, 500));
  });
});
```

What this does is on `keyup` it sets a 500ms delay before running `$('#output').text($(input).text())`, if another key is pressed before that happens, it cancels the timer and starts another...so it won't run until 500ms of idle.  Also by using [`$.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) to store the timer on the specific element, this generic solution work for any number of elements on a page.

---

As an aside, your `$('document').ready()` should be `$(document).ready()` or the shorter `$(function() {` like I have above, `"document"` (in quotes) runs a selector unnecessarily.

Comment: Cheers Nick,

One other question.

Functionally is there a difference between $(document).ready(){} and $(function(){});

Comment: @Hailwood - nope, it's just a shortcut :)